# как изменить стиль через css если он прописан жестко в html?

Tags: css

если вставить любой  html и сss на страницу с прописанным кодом то чтобы онулировались те жесткие стили

```html
<p class="prod-excerpt">
   <img alt="" src="https://images.ua.prom.st.jpg" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; width: 640px; height: 371px;">
</p>
```

пользователь может вставить любой html css в блок prod-excerptв данном случае картинку и прописал в нее стили, но они могут не соответвовать размеру сайта поэтому их нужно через css сделать как нужно
прописываю в css

```
#major .fancybox-opened .prod-excerpt img{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

ничего не меняется

Answer (score 1):

Определение через `style="` имеет приоритет перед `.css` файлами.

Можно использовать еще `important` около определения.

Но лучше поправить HTML, или его генерацию.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант при помощи `!important`

```css
.prod-excerpt > img {
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<p class="prod-excerpt">
   <img alt="" src="https://images.ua.prom.st.jpg" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; width: 640px; height: 371px;">
</p>
```

---

Вариант при помощи **JavaScript**

```js
let els = document.querySelectorAll('.prod-excerpt > img');
for(let el of els) {
  el.style.marginLeft = '';
  el.style.marginRight = '';
  el.style.width = '';
}
```

```css
.prod-excerpt > img {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p class="prod-excerpt">
   <img alt="" src="https://images.ua.prom.st.jpg" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; width: 640px; height: 371px;">
</p>
```

---

Вариант на **jQuery**

```js
$('.prod-excerpt > img').css({
  'margin-left': '',
  'margin-right': '',
  'width': ''
});
```

```css
.prod-excerpt > img {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="prod-excerpt">
   <img alt="" src="https://images.ua.prom.st.jpg" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px; width: 640px; height: 371px;">
</p>
```